# how to change column mode and class from character to compute mean in r programming on a dataset ,windows10 64 bit ,R 3.3.2,

Tags: r

I tried different codes those with function() and this too

```
data<-list(hw1_data$Ozone)
> data.numbers=sapply(data,as.numeric)
```

and many others still cannot figure how come its not happening

```
hw1_data$Ozone
  [1] "41"  "36"  "12"  "18"  "NA"  "28"  "23"  "19"  "8"   "NA"  "7"   "16"  "11" 
 [14] "14"  "18"  "14"  "34"  "6"   "30"  "11"  "1"   "11"  "4"   "32"  "NA"  "NA" 
 [27] "NA"  "23"  "45"  "115" "37"  "NA"  "NA"  "NA"  "NA"  "NA"  "NA"  "29"  "NA" 
 [40] "71"  "39"  "NA"  "NA"  "23"  "NA"  "NA"  "21"  "37"  "20"  "12"  "13"  "NA" 
 [53] "NA"  "NA"  "NA"  "NA"  "NA"  "NA"  "NA"  "NA"  "NA"  "135" "49"  "32"  "NA" 
 [66] "64"  "40"  "77"  "97"  "97"  "85"  "NA"  "10"  "27"  "NA"  "7"   "48"  "35" 
 [79] "61"  "79"  "63"  "16"  "NA"  "NA"  "80"  "108" "20"  "52"  "82"  "50"  "64" 
 [92] "59"  "39"  "9"   "16"  "78"  "35"  "66"  "122" "89"  "110" "NA"  "NA"  "44" 
[105] "28"  "65"  "NA"  "22"  "59"  "23"  "31"  "44"  "21"  "9"   "NA"  "45"  "168"
[118] "73"  "NA"  "76"  "118" "84"  "85"  "96"  "78"  "73"  "91"  "47"  "32"  "20" 
[131] "23"  "21"  "24"  "44"  "21"  "28"  "9"   "13"  "46"  "18"  "13"  "24"  "16" 
[144] "13"  "23"  "36"  "7"   "14"  "30"  "NA"  "14"  "18"  "20" 
> as.numeric(x)
  [1]  41  36  12  18  NA  28  23  19   8  NA   7  16  11  14  18  14  34   6  30  11
 [21]   1  11   4  32  NA  NA  NA  23  45 115  37  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  29  NA  71
 [41]  39  NA  NA  23  NA  NA  21  37  20  12  13  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
 [61]  NA 135  49  32  NA  64  40  77  97  97  85  NA  10  27  NA   7  48  35  61  79
 [81]  63  16  NA  NA  80 108  20  52  82  50  64  59  39   9  16  78  35  66 122  89
[101] 110  NA  NA  44  28  65  NA  22  59  23  31  44  21   9  NA  45 168  73  NA  76
[121] 118  84  85  96  78  73  91  47  32  20  23  21  24  44  21  28   9  13  46  18
[141]  13  24  16  13  23  36   7  14  30  NA  14  18  20
Warning message:
NAs introduced by coercion 


> mean(x)
[1] NA
Warning message:
In mean.default(x) : argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
>
```

Answer (score 0):

As your original data include NA's try using

```
mean(as.numeric(x),na.rm=TRUE)
```

Comment: mean(x,na.rm=TRUE)
[1] NA
Warning message:
In mean.default(x, na.rm = TRUE) :
  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA      it still shows the same error ...i cant figure out whats happening .

Comment: Before performing mean run class(x) and post output

Comment: It worked..thanx a ton .. it stil showed the class as "character " but it did worked to compute mean..

Comment: That was because you were changing the class using as.numeric(x) from character to numeric but you weren't saving the as.numeric(x) to a new object or replace existing x.

Comment: so class(x) saved it as numeric so we could get mean ,please bear with me then why it showed it still as character

Comment: as.numeric converted it to numeric you should have saved the numeric version as x<- as.numeric(x)